# Count child nodes of node matching listbox item

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, selectedindexchanged

Im having a problem here with selected index change. My xml file contains module number, module name, assesments, credits etc. What im trying to achieve here is - some course details are loaded into listbox from xml (module name and code) but when user selects a module, label should display how many assessments that module has.
Here is my XML file sample

```
<module>
    <moduleCode>ECWM618</moduleCode>
    <moduleTitle>Semantic and Social Web</moduleTitle>
    <credits>15</credits>
    <semester>2</semester>
    <assessmentDetails>
      <assessment>
        <assessmentName>Coursework1</assessmentName>
        <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
        <assessmentWeighting>25</assessmentWeighting>
      </assessment>
      <assessment>
        <assessmentName>Coursework2</assessmentName>
        <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
        <assessmentWeighting>25</assessmentWeighting>
      </assessment>
      <assessment>
        <assessmentName>Exam</assessmentName>
        <assessmentType>Exam</assessmentType>
        <assessmentWeighting>50</assessmentWeighting>
      </assessment>
    </assessmentDetails>
  </module>
```

And here is the code i got

```
private void moduleSummaryBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // when module from modulelist is selected, it read all indicies assigned to the module.
            //!!!!!!!! it reads last node only :(?  wtf im tired ...lol 
            //            
                // read data from modulelist
                string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"myCourse.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                XmlReader moduleReader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
                moduleReader.Read();
                while (moduleReader.Read())
                {
                    int assessmentNo = 0;
                    bool match = false;
                    moduleReader.MoveToElement();

                    if (moduleReader.Name == "assessmentName")
                    {
                        moduleReader.Read();// reads xml file.
                        XmlNodeType nType = moduleReader.NodeType; //XmlNodeType Specifies the type of node. If node matches specified name = true.
                        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)// if node type match XmlNodeType ( and there is some text in it) statement becomes true
                        {
                            this.assno.Text = (moduleReader.Value.ToString()); //set mcode label to matched node.                            
                        }
                    }

                    if (moduleReader.Value.ToString() == moduleSummaryBox.Items[moduleSummaryBox.SelectedIndex].ToString())
                    {
                        match = true;
                    }

                    if (match == true)
                    {
                        break;                        
                    }


            }
        }
```

Help appreciated thank you :)

EDIT: 
This is what goes into listbox

```
moduleSummaryBox.Items.Clear();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"myCourse.xml");

            XmlNodeList levelList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("level"+l_level);
            foreach (XmlNode node in levelList)
            {
                XmlElement moduleElement = (XmlElement)node;
                XmlNodeList modules_individ = moduleElement.GetElementsByTagName("module");
                foreach (XmlNode nodes in modules_individ)
                {
                    XmlElement moduleSeperator = (XmlElement)nodes;
                    string ll_moduleCode = moduleSeperator.GetElementsByTagName("moduleCode")[0].InnerText;
                    string ll_moduleTitle = moduleSeperator.GetElementsByTagName("moduleTitle")[0].InnerText;                    
                    moduleSummaryBox.Items.Add(ll_moduleCode+" : " + ll_moduleTitle+" ");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the exact content of the listbox? Show us the strings it contains. You should also describe what the problem is as part of the question, not leaving it in the comments of your code. You never count the number of assignment nodes in any case.

Comment: why not use XPath? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/en-us

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok i have mannaged to count number of assessments... however the code counts ALL assessments inside the XML but not the number assessments of selected index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Try With the code sample below:-

```
const string xmlString =
                "<module><moduleCode>ECWM618</moduleCode><moduleTitle>Semantic and Social Web</moduleTitle><credits>15</credits>" +
                "<semester>2</semester><assessmentDetails><assessment><assessmentName>Coursework1</assessmentName><assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>" +
                "<assessmentWeighting>25</assessmentWeighting></assessment><assessment><assessmentName>Coursework2</assessmentName><assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>" +
                "<assessmentWeighting>25</assessmentWeighting></assessment><assessment><assessmentName>Exam</assessmentName><assessmentType>Exam</assessmentType><assessmentWeighting>50</assessmentWeighting></assessment></assessmentDetails></module>";

            var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
            var qry =
                xml.Descendants()
                    .Where(e => e.Name == "moduleCode" && e.Value == "ECWM618")
                    .Ancestors()
                    .Descendants()
                    .Where(e => e.Name == "assessmentDetails")
                    .Elements("assessment").Count();
```